# Sequelize v5 findAndCountAll Include Columns

Tags: attributes, sequelize.js

When using findAndCountAll sequelize runs two queries. The first does the count but it doesn't include any of the attribute fields. Is there any way to make the count query include the attribute fields?

Comment: Probably not due to the way SQL works. `count` is an aggregator function, whereas the attribute fields are not. Could you include an example of what you hope the result would look like? If you want the `count` included inline with all your other columns, you'd need to introduce a `group by` clause for every attribute in the query. It's possible but kind of tedious

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to include attributes in `count` query because it's used for counting the total number of records that satisfy all indicated conditions and `count` query doesn't use `limit` and `offset` parameters for that same reason unlike `SELECT` query to get limited number of records with all indicated attributes.
If you have 100 records that meet all conditions and you also indicated `limit: 10` and `offset:20` then you will get 10 records starting from offset 20 and `count` will be equal to 100. This will allow you to determine how many `pages` of records you can get.